# Visual Studio better find symbol navigation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, find, fuzzy-search

I am looking for a "find symbol" type navigation for visual studio C++, for when you're browsing a large codebase, and you want to find some specific functionality but you don't know exactly what it will be called or where it will be (I guess some kind of fuzzy symbol search).

Visual studio has "go-to symbol" described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/go-to?view=vs-2022. However I am finding it fairly unusable; whatever matching algorithm they're using is pretty useless for this use case, for example something like

```
virtual FPathFollowingRequestResult MoveTo(const FAIMoveRequest& MoveRequest, FNavPathSharedPtr* OutPath = nullptr);
```

won't match the search terms "controller move to" or "ai move" or "move path". Likewise

```
FTransform ExtractRootMotionFromTrackRange(float StartTrackPosition, float EndTrackPosition) const;
```

cannot be found with "root motion transform" or "root motion position". I guess the main issue is it can't mix and match between the typename, function name and parameter names. And it even seems too strict within the function name (e.g. "nav cast" won't match `NavigationRaycast`). It seems in order to be in any way effective with this search window you have to pretty much exactly know the function name.

Am I missing a better way in-built into VS for this kind of search? I would also be happy with an extension if it were quite low-impact and not too expensive (e.g. I think visual assist's fuzzy symbol search is great and would probably match all these cases, but VA seems to come with its own performance / parsing issues on very large projects, has a ton of functionality I wouldn't need, and is quite expensive)

Comment: I've never used this `Go To` command before. I've used it now and it seems it's not good for finding symbols if you provide a word in the middle of the full symbol name (e.g. go to `descending` won't list `range_of_numbers_in_descending_order`). I have to admit I usually do `CTRL + SHIFT + F`, plus check `Use regular expressions`, plus `Look in Entire Workspace` for searching texts.

Comment: Waiting for the "Ermagerd! Don't use `goto`!" comments.

Answer (score 0):

Currently VS2022 already supports symbol search and feature search. For details, I suggest you refer to this [issue](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/introducing-a-new-way-to-search-your-code-and-visual-studio-features/#what-is-symbol-search).

> Visual Studio 17.2 Preview 3 introduces a brand-new All-In-One search
> experience that merges the existing VS Search (Ctrl + Q) and Go To
> (Ctrl + T) to allow you to search both your code and Visual Studio
> features quicker and easier than ever, all in the same place.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not what I'm after, this is a preview feature so need to download a separate build, but I checked it out and this feature has the same flaws as mentioned in the question. I suspect it uses the same underlying search engine as go-to symbol but they just changed the UI a bit.

Comment: @badger5000,Hi, you could refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) to use regular expressions when searching.